# Speed up application performance with Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have written a VB.Net application which uses MS Access 2010 as the database. The database is kept in network drive on a server which is in the US. The application is being used by users in Germany, China, Italy, and India apart from the US users.

For a US user performance of the application is excellent, but for all other users from other regions, the performance is really not great. Every database action takes at least a minute to complete. Please help me to improve the situation.

Comment: Do the users in each country need to be aware of the other country's data? I.e. could you keep multiple access databases local to each country and reconcile them out of hours.

Comment: If you share the physical _accdb_ file from a file share across WAN lines, you need stable fibre connections at speeds similar to LAN speed, at least 10 Mb/s both ways. If speed is lower, you should move the backend to an SQL engine like _SQL Server_. The _Express_ edition is free.

Answer (score 1):

Expand from Access back-end to MS SQL/MySQL back-end. To do that, you need to either host MS SQL or MySQL on a dedicated ip/intranet address. MS Access has an inbuilt function to upgrade back-end tables to MS SQL server use that or recreate the back-end in MySQL.

Other than that, multiple users from multiple remote locations + shared network drive will drive everyone crazy